# Is Flintheart Glomgold's backstory ever mentioned in the comics?

Tags: ducktales, donald-duck

In Ducktales S02E03, we find out the backstory of Flintheart Glomgold and his relationship to Scrooge.

Is this the first time in the Duckverse that his backstory is mentioned, or is it mentioned in the comics as well?

If yes, are there differences in the backstory?

Comment: Only using a quick Google through the wikis, it looks like he really wasn't given a background until *The Life and Times of Scrooge McDuck*, which postdates the original *Ducktales* series.

Comment: Which, honestly, surprised me. I didn't remember the cartoon series as being that old. I mean, I watched it as a... oh.

Comment: @TheAsh  I added several paragraphs to my answer on 03-21-2021..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I remember, Flintheart Glomgold was introduced as a stranger to Scrooge, a Boer duck from South Africa, in the first comic to feature him, where Scrooge and Glomgold measured their wealth to see who was the richest duck in the world and ended up measuring the lengths of their balls of string to decide.  That was "The Second-Richest Duck" by Carl Barks in *Uncle Scrooge* # 15, September 1956.

And there wasn't any clue that Scrooge and Glomgold had any kind of backstory before their meeting in 1955 in his next appearances in "The Money Champ", September 1959, and "So Far and no Safari" in January 1966.

Decades later, Don Rosa in *The Life and Times of Scrooge McDuck* Part 6 "The Terror of the Transvaal" depicted young Scrooge and Glomgold meeting and fighting  each other in the South African Gold Rush of 1886.  Though Glomgold learned Scrooge's name, Rosa was careful to be sure that Scrooge never learned Glomgold's name and so didn't recognize that scoundrel when he met his billionaire rival in the 1950s and 60s.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flintheart_Glomgold[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flintheart_Glomgold%5B1%5D)

I note that in the *Duck Tales* 2017 episode "The Ballad of Duke Baloney!", November 3, 2018, Glomgbold is given a differnt backstory than Rosa gave him.  In that episode Glomgold was much younger than Uncle Scrooge, thus explaining why Glomgold is still alive.  They met in South Africa when Glomgold was a boy and Scrooge got a shoe shine from Glomgold - things didn't go well and that caused Glomgold's feud with Scrooge.

In "The Life and Crimes of Scrooge McDuck!", March 8, 2021, Glomgold claimed that a later encounter with Scrooge made him the evil villain he was.  The wealthy Glomgold was trying to buy the love of the people of Duckburg when Scrooge beat him to a treasure and left Glomgold stranded in a shark cave.

And I have read that in the 1987 *Duck Tales*  Glomgold was made a Scotsman (or Scotsduck) instead of a South African Boer and so had a different orgin that in either the Comics or *Duck Tales* 2017.